# Magento - screen goes blank after saving products

Tags: php, magento

When I am saving simple products from the magento backend, the screen goes blank.

The error I am getting is

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getStores() on a non-object in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php on line 155
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/url')` returns a non-object - check whether it is missing or rewritten by any 3-rd party module.

Latter can be done by searching the *.php files in the directory for this string: `"extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url"`